# How to make a ldap authentication service with passport-ldapauth

Tags: node.js, passport.js, ldapauth

I'm trying to create a rest service which would authenticate a user with their username and password.

The data provided to me for doing it is (data is example, not what I actually got):
-host: 10.10.10.10
-port: 443
-attribute: uid
-base: dc=example, dc=corp
-admin_user: "cn=ex,ou=applications,dc=example,dc=corp"
-admin_password: "example123"

What I've tried is using node.js with passport-ldapauth with the following code:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const port = 443;
var passport = require('passport');
const LdapStrategy = require('passport-ldapauth');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const OPTS = {
    server: {
        url: 'LDAP://10.10.10.10/dc=example, dc=corp',
        port: 443,
        bindDN: 'dc=example, dc=corp'
    }
};

passport.use(new LdapStrategy(OPTS));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(passport.initialize());

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('ldapauth', {session:     false}), function(req, res){
    res.send({status: 'ok'});
});

app.listen(port, () =>{
    console.log('Listening');
})
```

But I'm not even receving a response from the server with postman calling to http://localhost/login with username and password passed as json or urlencoded, I don't know if the problem is in my side or on server side.

Any help will be much appreciated.